# Versioning with ODR? (On-Demand Resources)

Tags: ios, versioning, auto-update, on-demand-resources

I have found no mention of how versioning is handled by Apple with their On-Demand Resources (ODR) feature.

What happens when I need to replace an uploaded resource with a new version? Can I simply replace a resource on Apple’s server?

If so, how does that affect existing users? Will an existing user’s app with that resource automatically have it replaced?

Comment: hi, I have no idea but we have an issue with our game, assets are packed in bundle with our egnine so we are able to detect the bundle is outdated, but when we request the same tag again , it does not download, even after calling endAccessingResources & making a new instance of NSBundleResourceRequest

Answer (score 3):

If you ship a version 2.0 of your app with the same tags but the assets have been updated, iOS will redownload the assets that changed.

See video (around 21 minutes)

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/221/

Comment: The link leads to the wwdc2016 homepage - which video is this referring to? Would be helpful if you have time to update the link.